# Calling JS file in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Hi Im trying to call a external JavaScript file called `ts.js` as follows.
Can some one tell me whether the following approach is right or wrong and reasons for your recommendation.

Thanks you

```
$variable .= '<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Save" onclick="ts.js" />';
```

Comment: if you want to use something from ts.js just include it in header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the JavaScript file in the markup and then specify a function from it to be executed on click of the input.

So, say, in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="ts.js"></script>
```

And in your construction of the element(s):

```
$variable .= '<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Save" onclick="functionFromTSJS();" />';
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language and you can not call JavaScript from it. Because javascript is a client-side language and actually the browser runs it.

And even if it is possible, on the `onClick` method, you should use a function not a javascript file.

Javascript files can be included like :

`<script src="ts.js" type="text/javascript">`

After you imported the file like this you can use any functions in it on the `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery you can use

```
onclick="$.getScript('ts.js');"
```

with normal javascript I think that you only need to include the javascript in head

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'ts.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

you can wrap it with a function like load

```
function load() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'ts.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

and use

```
onclick="load('ts.js');"
```